# About Particle Density and PDF in Einstein's Paper on Brownian Motion

Tags: brownian-motion

In Einstein's paper, he deduced that the diffusion equation is satisfied for the number of particles per unit volume ($f(x, t)$), i.e
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=D\cdot \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}$$

The solution of this equation for $N$ particles starting at the origin is
$$f(x, t)=\frac{N}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{4Dt}}$$

Which is the PDF of a normal distribution (with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2= 2Dt$). My question is, how does this expression for the *particle density* tell us anything about the *probability density function* describing the movements of an individual particle? Why does the fact that the particle density is distributed normally imply the same for the PDF of incrementing by $\Delta$ in a small time $\tau$?

[In this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5476231/#R50), is is said that the PDF itself satisfies the above diffusion equation, which seems to not be what Einstein wrote in his paper.

I would appreciate an answer to my confusion (perhaps there is some argument for the equal treatment of the PDF and $f$?). Thanks.